# FOSUserBundle registration : targetUrl does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle with symfony2 and after registration (route /register), I received an error 500 on route /confirmed with the following message :

> Variable "targetUrl" does not exist in FOSUserBundle:Registration:confirmed.html.twig at line 9

I see some solved threads by setting `always_use_default_target_path: true` in security.yml but this not worked for me.

Need help !

EDIT : clearing cache does not change anything

EDIT 2 :

Information about environment 
Os : ArchLinux

Php : version 7.0.6

Nginx : version 1.10.0

Symfony : 2.7.13

Code of custom template file (FOSUserBundle:Registration:confirmed.html.twig located in app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Registration/ )

```
    {% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{% block fos_user_content %}
        <div class="modal-header"><h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirmed !</h4></div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>{{ 'registration.confirmed'|trans({'%username%': user.username}) }}</p>
            {% if targetUrl %}
                <p><a href="{{ targetUrl }}">{{ 'registration.back'|trans }}</a></p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" >
        $('#register').on('hide.bs.modal', function(ev) 
        {
            location.reload(true);
        })
        </script>
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

After paste my code, written few month ago, I see that I use "targetUrl" variable. 
So... Why symfony consider it as "unknow" in it's own template but not in mine ?

State of problem :

At this times, renaming original template located in FOSUserBundle install dir (vendors/...) solve the problem, but it's really ugly. 
It seems that for this route and only for this route (register/confirmed), symfony ignore my custom template while it can be found in install dir...

Comment: Partially solved. I don't know why, but symfony didn't check app/Ressource at first time and so ignore my override of the template. Need to rename/del the original file...

Comment: According to your comment you copied and change the content of the `FOSUserBundle:Registration:confirmed.html.twig` file, can you please add the file content in your question?

Comment: Code added. But it has been worked the last month, and other template in same folder works well

Comment: I can't understand... the official template use targetUrl, and it crash. My template use targetUrl, and it works. Any similar problems with targetUrl are solved by setting default_target_path in security.yml. My template which use targetUrl redirect to /, but my default_target_path was to /index. My login template don't use targetUrl but use default_target_path (this is tested).

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> I don't know why, but symfony didn't check app/Ressource at first time and so ignore my override of the template. Need to rename/del the original file...

Finding the correct path where an overriding file must be placed can be tricky, it should be `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Registration/confirmed.html.twig` in your case.

Comment: My path is OK. And after renaming original file (from FOSUserBundle), symfony use my file (and also, registration.html.twig is present in my app/Resources/... and works well, symfony use it without any other "hack"). Maybe, FOSUserBundle use directly the template file for confirmed route (hard coded links ?) ?

Comment: @Loy I wasn't sure it was the answer. Feel free to add an answer with your solution, it may help some other users.

Comment: At this times, my solution is very ugly, because I was modified directly vendors/friendsofsymfony/... in order to force symfony to use my own template in app/Resource/... folder :/ I will edit my question to add some information about the problem